# parse string for subdomain in php

Tags: php, parsing

How can i find if a string has subdomain existing if there is no scheme / host present.

eg: `$url="sub.main.com/images/sample.jpg";`

I am trying to parse the url for images, and I am using `parse_url` for most cases.

But given the url strings can some in different flavors,
eg:

```
/images/sample.jpg
//main.com/images/sample.jpg
images/sample.jpg
```

etc, I am trying to address the different cases one by one. Right now, I am finding it hard to detect if a string has subdomain present or not.

so for a string such as $url="sub.main.com/images/sample.jpg";` i would like to extract the subdomain, and for a string such as images/sample.jpg, i would like to find out that there is no subdomain

Comment: Is the primary domain `main.com` always the same? If so, it is easy to detect the presence of the main domain, and if it has a subdomain component.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski No that is the problem. The url comes from users. It if was the same, there are answers on SO that deals with the case. I even tried this. http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/234954-how-to-get-the-value-of-subdomain/ but it returns images as subdomain if url given is images/sample.jpg. i would like to get null in that case.

Comment: maybe in your particular set of urls this wouldn't occur, but keep in mind that `http://www.example.com/www.google.com/sample.jpg` is a valid url. I think you may need to take advantage of any restrictions that might exist in your data set to develop a heuristic or rule that works for your case.

Comment: @rambocoder Thanks,you are very right, it is possible to have complex url inside url cases . but I am trying to to address the most common cases. Once the basics are done, I will work out a more enhanced rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. I've fiddled around with this for a while; this method inevitably isn't perfect, but it may start you down the right path.

My solution begins with the two source files in this repository: https://github.com/usrflo/registered-domain-libs/tree/master/PHP

First, you may need to modify regDomain.inc.php to change an instance of `$signingDomainParts = split('\.', $signingDomain);` to `$signingDomainParts = preg_split('/\./', $signingDomain);` if split is deprecated in your php version.

Once you've got those saved, try this testing code, I put all of the URLs mentioned in the thread here as test cases:

```
<?php
require_once("effectiveTLDs.inc.php");
require_once("regDomain.inc.php");
$tests = Array("/images/sample.jpg","//main.com/images/sample.jpg","images/sample.jpg", "sub.main.com/images/sample.jpg", "http://www.example.com/www.google.com/sample.jpg", "amazon.co.uk/images/sample.jpg", "amazon.com/images/sample.jpg", "http://sub2.sub.main.co.uk/images/sample.jpg", "sub2.sub.main.co.uk/images/sample.jpg");
foreach($tests as $test)
{
    echo "Attempting $test.<BR/>";
    $one = parse_url($test);
    if(!array_key_exists("host", $one))
    {
        echo "Converting to: http://$test";
        echo "<BR/>";
        $one = parse_url("http://$test");
    }
    if(!$one){echo "<BR/>";continue;}
    echo "parse_url parts: ";
    print_r($one);
    echo "<BR/>";
    if($one && array_key_exists("host", $one))
    {
        $domain = getRegisteredDomain($one["host"], $tldTree);
        if(sizeof($domain))
        {
            $two = explode(".", $domain);
            echo "domain parts: ";
            print_r($two);
            echo "<BR/>";
            if(sizeof($two))
            {
                $three = array_diff(explode(".", $one["host"]), $two);
                if(sizeof($three))
                {
                    echo "Hark! A subdomain!: ";
                    print_r($three);
                    echo "<BR/>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<BR/>";

}

?>
```

This code identifies the following of the test-cases as having subdomains:

```
Attempting sub.main.com/images/sample.jpg.
Hark! A subdomain!: Array ( [0] => sub ) 

Attempting http://www.example.com/www.google.com/sample.jpg.
Hark! A subdomain!: Array ( [0] => www ) 

Attempting http://sub2.sub.main.co.uk/images/sample.jpg.
Hark! A subdomain!: Array ( [0] => sub2 [1] => sub ) 

Attempting sub2.sub.main.co.uk/images/sample.jpg.
Hark! A subdomain!: Array ( [0] => sub2 [1] => sub )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
$url = 'sub.main.com/images/sample.jpg';    
$arr = explode('/',$url);

$domain = $arr[0];
$string = $arr[1];

$arr2 = explode('.',$domain);

if(count($arr2)>2) {
    $subdomain = $arr2[0];
    echo $subdomain;
}
?>
```

Comment: What about something like `amazon.co.uk/images/sample.jpg`? (edit: or, for that matter, `amazon.com/images/sample.jpg`)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://sub.main.com/images/sample.jpg';
$arr = explode('/',$url);

$pieces = parse_url($url);

$domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) 
{ 
  $main_domain=$regs['domain'];
}

$host=$pieces['host'];
$path=$pieces['path'];

if($host != $main_domain)
{
    $arr2 = explode('.',$host); 
    $subdomain = $arr2[0];
    echo $subdomain;
}

$string=substr($path,1,strlen($path));

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$url="sub.main.com/images/sample.jpg";

preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^.]+).?([^/]+)@i',$url, $hits);
print_r($hits);
?>
```

This should output something like:

```
Array ( [0] => sub.main.com [1] => sub [2] => main.com )
```

Comment: $url="http://sub2.sub.main.co.uk/images/sample.jpg"; Array ( [0] => http://sub2.sub.main.co.uk [1] => sub2 [2] => sub.main.co.uk )

Comment: @Chris well, true, but array gets "images" if the url is images/sample.jpg. is there a way to modify teh preg_match?